# Why can we pass limit under integral sign in proof of solving Poisson's equation? (Evans PDE)

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde, poissons-equation

On page 23 of Lawrence Evans' Partial Differential Equations text (2nd edition) he claims that
$$\frac{ f( x + he_i - y) - f( x-y)}{h} \to \frac{ \partial f}{ \partial x_i} ( x-y)$$
uniformly on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $h \to 0$. So

$$\frac{ \partial u}{ \partial x_i } (x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n }\Phi(y) \frac{ \partial f}{ \partial x_i} ( x- y) dy$$
Why does this hold true? I have proved uniform convergence as follows:

Proof: It suffices to show that
$$\underbrace{ \frac{ f( x + h e_i - y ) - f( x-y) }{ h} - \frac{ \partial f}{ \partial x_i } ( x-y)}_{g_h(y)}  \to 0 $$
uniformly as $h \to 0$. But by the Mean Value Theorem, for each $h$ there exists a $\theta_h$ such that $0 < \theta_h < 1$ and $\frac{ f( x + h e_i - y ) - f( x-y) }{ h}  = f_{x_i} ( x+ \theta_h h e_i - y) $. So
\begin{align*} g_h(y) &=  \frac{ f( x + h e_i - y ) - f( x-y) }{ h} - \frac{ \partial f}{ \partial x_i } ( x-y) \\
&=  f_{x_i} ( x+ \theta_h h e_i - y)  -  f_{x_i} ( x-y) 
\end{align*}
but $f_{x_i}$ is uniformly continuous ($f \in C_c^2$ so $f_{ x_i} \in C_c^1$ and therefore continuous on a compact set, so uniformly continuous). Therefore, regardless of $y$, for small enough $h$ this difference can be made arbitrarily small. So $g_h(y) \to 0$ uniformly, as we intended to show. QED.

But how does uniform convergence allow us to move the derivative through the integral sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\left|\frac{u(x+he_i)-u(x)}{h}- \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x-y)\, dy\right|\\= \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(y)\frac{f(x+he_i-y)-f(x-y)}{h}\, dy- \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x-y)\, dy\right|\\ \leqslant \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\Phi(y)|\left|\frac{f(x+he_i-y)-f(x-y)}{h}\, - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x-y)\right|\, dy$$

Let $x$ be fixed.  Since $f$ has **compact support**, the terms involving $f$ vanish for all $y$ outside some ball $B_R(0)$ of sufficiently large radius $R$.

Hence,

$$\left|\frac{u(x+he_i)-u(x)}{h}- \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x-y)\, dy\right|\\ \leqslant \int_{B_R(0)}|\Phi(y)|\underbrace{\left|\frac{f(x+he_i-y)-f(x-y)}{h}\, - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x-y)\right|}_{G(h,x,y)}\, dy$$

Note that the fundamental solution $\Phi$ has a singularity at $y=0$ but is integrable on any bounded neighborhood, so there exists $M > 0$ such that

$$\int_{B_R(0)}|\Phi(y)|< M$$

It has been established that $\displaystyle\frac{f(x+he_i-y)-f(x-y)}{h}$ converges uniformly to the partial derivative of $f$ as $h \to 0$.  Hence for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta(\epsilon) > 0$ such that if $|h| < \delta(\epsilon)$, then $0 \leqslant G(h,x,y) < \epsilon/M$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Thus, if $|h|< \delta(\epsilon)$, then we have

$$\left|\frac{u(x+he_i)-u(x)}{h}- \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x-y)\, dy\right|\leqslant \int_{B_R(0)}|\Phi(y)|\frac{\epsilon}{M}\, dy \leqslant \epsilon$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} (x) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{u(x+he_i)-u(x)}{h}= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x-y)\, dy$$